# Camel app on Liberty - JAXB Marshalling

Tags: apache-camel, websphere-liberty

I'm running a Camel application on Liberty Profile server. I'm taking a message from a queue, unmarshalling, mapping then marshalling. This was working fine but now I'm getting an error that JAXBDataBinding method getContextualNamespaceMap is not found.
I think this is because there is an older version of the jar in the server libs but I don't know why it started using it.

```
IBM Jar: com.ibm.ws.org.apache.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb.2.6.2_1.0.12
```

The issue is resolved if I switch to parent last class loading but its a very hacky way to fix it and is not a great option. Any other ideas? I'm thinking some feature or other dependency in my build may have pulled this jar in.

Comment: What features are you using and what JRE?

Comment: <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
dependencies {
 compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.16.2'
 compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-jms:2.16.2'
 compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-jaxb:2.16.2'
 compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-dozer:2.16.2'
 compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-cxf:2.16.2'
 compile 'javax.xml:jaxrpc:1.1'
 compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0'
 compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.11'
 compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.2.4.RELEASE'
 compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
 compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.6'
}

Comment: //test dependencies
 testCompile 'org.apache.camel:camel-test-spring:2.16.2'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.8.1'
 testCompile 'xmlunit:xmlunit:1.3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javaee7 feature contained a jaxsw version that clashed with the server version. Removing the javaee7 feature has resolved this issue. Remains to be seen whether or not I will to add it back in.

Answer (score 0):

So it does look like **getContextualNamespaceMap** is only available in newer versions of the **org.apache.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb** JAR than what is available in Liberty.

It might be that **parentLast** is the best option then.  (You already know how to do this but it's documented ([here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_alt_api.html)). If it leads to some other issues then do follow-up with another question.

I suppose it's conceivable you might be able to look at whatever is packaged within your application and try removing a set of things and picking them up from the Liberty runtime, to avoid running in **parentLast** mode.  E.g. if you are only referencing **getContextualNamespaceMap** because you have other code in your app but there is some alternative path you could have gone down entirely in the Liberty-provided modules, then in theory you could be OK.

I'm not familiar enough with the code paths in the modules in the CXF or Camel "stack" to guess whether that's a real-world likelihood though.

Comment: I must be using some JAR in the IBM libs that is referencing the databinding JAR right? I believe it would use the app version otherwise. So if I could figure out what JAR that is and add it to my application JARs could that resolve the issue?

Comment: I've confirmed that its the Camel-CXF dependency that causes the problem. I can marshal no problem if I remove the CXF endpoint, but I need that to call out to a web service.

Comment: Maybe my answer was confusing:  I was suggesting you were probably right to use the *parentLast* option to get the newer databinding JAR in your application rather than the older version in Liberty.      But then I said, "well, it's possible you might not NEED to if *parentLast* causes some other issue".  But if so then we're on to a more complicated problem that I wouldn't venture to comment on.   Make sense?

Comment: Sorry - got that, but we're hoping to avoid having to do that. I think the CXF dependency coming in must be looking for a JAR and not finding it, so resorting to using a server JAR which uses the databinding JAR off the server.